# Passing arguments to a method in my Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program and a module which I have imported. The imported module is called `mymod`.

What I want to do is to be able to terminate the module using a thread in my main program.  The code looks like this:

main program

```html
import threading
import time
import mymod

end_mymod = False

def thread_function(name):
    global end_mymod
    print("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Thread %s: finishing", name)
    end_mymod = True
    print(end_mymod)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
    x.start()

    print("starting mymod")
    mymod.main()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(end_mymod)
```

and `mymod` looks like this:

```html
import time

end_mymod = False

def main():
    global end_mymod
    while (not end_mymod):
        print(end_mymod)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem I have is that in the 'thread function' thread, I set `end_mymod` to `True` but for some reason it is not passed to `mymod`.

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: I am not too sure about what you meant to do exactly but the end_mymod you have accessed in thread has a different scope since you did not use global end_mymod in that thread function. Moreover the mymod variable is never set using end_mymod anywhere in the script. 

In case you feel I did not understand what you meant please help me to understand so that I may be able to help you with the same.

Comment: `end_bananas` is declared but never used

Comment: You seem to think that modifying a variable in one module will affect code looking at a differently named variable in another

Answer (score -1):

Your `end_mymod` in `thread_function` is just a **local** variable.

You need to declare it as `global` inside the function.

Comment: I tried that and still cannot see the change to end_mymod on the mymod module.